# Replace String with link - use string as linkvalue

Tags: jquery

I have a li element that I want to transform to a link. I have a script below that identifies the text - from here I want to make it a link instead. I want to use the string as a value in the link.

The label looks like this:

```
<li><label>Spårningsnummer</label>JVGL123456789</li>
```

And I want to append a link inside the label or replace the label with an a element with a link that looks like this:

```
http://www.dhl.se/sv/express/godssoekning.html?AWB=JVGL123456789&brand=DHL
```

Where this number is dynamic:

```
JVGL123456789
```

Script so far:

```
<li><label>Spårningsnummer</label>JVGL123456789</li>

if ($('fieldset li:contains("JVGL")').length > 0) {

}
```

I understand how to append pr replace the element with a static link - but how do I get the value from the string in my link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[`contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/)** and **[`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)** with condition `nodeType == 3` to get the text node, then wrap it with an anchor tag using **[`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)**.

```js
$('li:contains("JVGL")').each(function() {
  $text = $(this).contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
  });
  text = $text.text();
  $text.wrap('<a href="http://www.dhl.se/sv/express/godssoekning.html?AWB=' + text +  '&brand=DHL" ></a>')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
    <label>Spårningsnummer</label>JVGL123456789
</li>
```

Comment: That worked really good! And it looks so easy - very nice script. This will be bookmarked and studied, thanks again!